# Jquery click multiple IDs and get value

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, this

I'm trying to get the value of an element when a user click on it. This is my code:

```
<div id="heroes-selection" class="row dflex justify-content-left">
    <figure id="luna" class="heroes-pic border text-danger m-3" value="heroes.luna">
      <img class="animated-gif">
   </figure>

   <figure id="qop" class="heroes-pic border text-danger m-3" value="heroes.qop">
      <img class="animated-gif">
   </figure>
</div>
```

I've tried  to use Jquery `$(this)` and the result came out as `undefined`.

```
$(".heroes-pic").on("click", () => {
  player = $(this).attr("value");
  console.log(player);
});
```

My goal is to get the value `heroes.luna` when the user click on the figure with `id="luna"`. The same for `id="qop"`, I need to get the value `heroes.qop`. Thank you!

Comment: Just change arrow function ()=> to normal function().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the classic function instead of arrow function. `this` on arrow function refers to the `HTMLDocument` and on the object clicked. And that is the reason why you are not getting the correct result. You are getting attr value from `HTMLDocument`.

```js
$(".heroes-pic").on("click", function() {
  player = $(this).attr("value");
  console.log(player);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="heroes-selection" class="row dflex justify-content-left">
  <figure id="luna" class="heroes-pic border text-danger m-3" value="heroes.luna"> heroes.luna
    <img class="animated-gif">
  </figure>

  <figure id="qop" class="heroes-pic border text-danger m-3" value="heroes.qop"> heroes.qop
    <img class="animated-gif">
  </figure>

</div>
```

---

**Other option:** you can use `event.currentTarget` instead of `this` on arrow function

Like:

```js
$(".heroes-pic").on("click", (event) => {
  player = $(event.currentTarget).attr("value");
  console.log(player);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="heroes-selection" class="row dflex justify-content-left">
  <figure id="luna" class="heroes-pic border text-danger m-3" value="heroes.luna">
    <img class="animated-gif">heroes.luna
  </figure>

  <figure id="qop" class="heroes-pic border text-danger m-3" value="heroes.qop">
    <img class="animated-gif">heroes.qop
  </figure>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using an arrow function that binds the `this` parameter to the enclosing scope's this.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this

replace it with a function:

```
$(".heroes-pic").on("click", function () {
  player = $(this).attr("value");
  console.log(player);
}
```